# How to measure my code performance and database performance php

Tags: php, database, performance

I am using laravel 5 i have a big server which have high cost but after developing script my server have tons of load on database i have already contact to my server host he say the script is the issue may be code is poor. i don't know why it's happening need help how i can measure my code with database performance.

I want to know which my function, controller take so much load and why my database is overloading.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you have indexes on your tables where needed? Use `EXPLAIN` to see how the database processes a query and look for example where temporary tables are created. Use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see which queries and how many are actually executing on the server.

Comment: Have a look at `xdebug` and services like New Relic that offer profiling. But if you are seeing high load on the DB, as @syck said, use `EXPLAIN` to see if your queries can be improved.

Comment: What is EXPLAIN and SHOW PROCESSLIST and how to use it and where to use it? @syck

Comment: Would you please be so kind and have a look at the documentation? If you have phpmyadmin installed, you can execute that stuff there; if not, you should.

Comment: I have phpmyadmin installed and i am reading this article for understand http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/ Explain but i don't understand well

Answer (score 0):

Use [xhprof](https://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) ([GitHub](https://github.com/phacility/xhprof)) for PHP. It can nail down any problematic piece if code.

DB profilers may vary, depending on RDBMS you use, but for PostgreSQL I'd strongly recommend [pgBadger](https://github.com/dalibo/pgbadger).